# I want to subtract text value have class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, subtraction

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Sum of all TextBox values using jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#addAll").click(function() {
                var add = 0;
                $(".amt").each(function() {
                    add -= Number($(this).val());
                });
                $("#para").text("Sum of all textboxes is : " + add);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="Text1" class="amt" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="Text2" class="amt" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="Text3" class="amt" type="text" /><br />  
    <input id="addAll" type="button" value="Sum all Textboxes" /><br />
    <p id="para" />
</body>
</html>
```

but i couldn't get the actual result. please help me

Comment: Because you have called the variable 'add' and you're doing subtraction!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ApjgJ/ is a fiddle of your code (with some default values put in). It seems to work (assuming it is meant to subtract all the numbers from zero). Can you clarify exactly what result you are getting and what result you expect?

Comment: It might just be me but "Sum all...", addAll, add - then you subtract just seems confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function() {
    $("#addAll").click(function() {
        var add = 0;
        $(".amt").each(function() {
            add += parseInt($(this).val() || 0, 10);
        });
        $("#para").text("Sum of all textboxes is : " + add);
    });
});
```

Using `parseInt`. Additionally, you should use `+=` if you're trying to sum the values.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/S9H6A/

---

**Update:** If you're trying to subtract all values in the text boxes, then your problem is that you're initializing the total to 0. Try something like this instead (Also added code from @[Praveen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223107/i-want-to-subtract-text-value-have-class-in-jquery/5223162#5223162)'s answer which uses `|| 0` to default empty `input`s to 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#addAll").click(function() {
        var total;
        $(".amt").each(function() {
            if (typeof total === 'undefined') {
                total = parseInt($(this).val() || 0, 10);
            }
            else {
                total -= parseInt($(this).val() || 0, 10);
            }
        });
        $("#para").text("Sum of all textboxes is : " + total);
    });
});
```

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/S9H6A/4/

Comment: this code is not working .The subtraction of class shows negetive values .. any other idea s appreciatable

Comment: @reju: Just updated with a working example and using `+=` instead (wasn't sure if you were actually trying to subtract or add).

Comment: yeah i m trying subtract group of elements using class.i did addition but subtraction is not working .. any idea about this?

Comment: @reju: That's probably because you're initializing `add` to 0.

Comment: Why parseInt instead of Number?

Comment: @reju: you have three text boxes. Which do you want to take away from which? the last two away from the first?

Comment: @Chris: No particular reason, I just prefer `parseInt`. Is there a reason to go with one or the other?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: I'm not sure really. The only difference I can see from empirical testing is that you seem to need a minor hack with ParseInt to get it to deal with an empty string but Number() just seems to deal with it fine. I'm not bothered enough to have withheld my +1 though, don't worry. ;-) P.S. You need to add that hack to your else in the if statement or bizzrre thigns start happeing if you leave that middle box blank (since !NaN is apparently true).

Answer (score 0):

replace this `add -= Number($(this).val());` with `add -= parseInt($(this).val()|| 0,10);`

Comment: this one also not working .... please check with this.. http://jsfiddle.net/S9H6A/

Comment: what advantage does parseInt have over Number? It seems to work just fine with Number... In fact, possibly better since Number seems to treat an empty textbox as a zero...

Comment: @reju: It does if you also add the `||0`.

Comment: @reju i just tried http://jsfiddle.net/S9H6A/ , its running fine, could you tell with what values are you trying??

Comment: @Brad: Oh yeah, it does seem to deal with empty text boxes. I swear it didn't when I tested it jsut now but I probabyl just forgot to tell jsfiddle to update or something. ;-)